# Instantiate game object loaded from assetbundle lost animation clip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle, animator

I Had all my Npc's prefab packed  into assetbundle with all  dependencies,but when I finished loading all dependencies of one npc and instantiate it into scene, some times the animation clip on it can't be played. I print animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0).Length and I found it is 0.So it seems that I had lost all animation clip of this animator.
The funny thing is that it doesn't happed on all npc,and I can't find any differences between them.

I used following codes to attached assetbundle name to all assets.

```
private void SelectionAndAssetsListChange()
{
    EditorUtility.ClearProgressBar();
    selection = Selection.objects;
    //assets = new AssetImporter[selection.Length];
    if (selection.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < selection.Length; i++)
        {
            string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(selection[i]);                
           
            string[] dps = AssetDatabase.GetDependencies(assetPath);
            int length = dps.Length;                 
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var dp in dps)
            {
                if (EditorUtility.DisplayCancelableProgressBar("Changing Assets's ab name ", "Changing No." + index + "/" + length, (float)index / length))
                {
                    EditorUtility.ClearProgressBar();
                    return;
                }

                if (dp.EndsWith(".cs"))
                    continue;
                AssetImporter dpAsset = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(dp);                    
                string assetNameDPs = dp.Substring("Assets".Length + 1);                                        
                assetNameDPs = assetNameDPs.Replace(Path.GetExtension(assetNameDPs), ".data");
                assetNameDPs = Path.Combine("assetbundle", assetNameDPs);
                assetNameDPs = assetNameDPs.Replace("\\", "/");
                dpAsset.assetBundleName = assetNameDPs;
                index++;
            }
            EditorUtility.ClearProgressBar();
        }
    }
}
```

Following Codes are used to load assetbundle ,i used 2 dictionaries  TempABGO_Dict and TempDPSAB_Dict to
make sure make sure it doesn't double load.

```
IEnumerator SingleTempGOABLoad(string abName)
{
   
        string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + abName;

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            Debug.Log("Can't find path:" + path);
            yield break;
        }

        Debug.Log(" 1 SingleTempGOABLoad :" + abName);
        
        if (TempABGO_Dict.ContainsKey(abName))
            yield break;

        string[] allDps = mainManifest.GetAllDependencies(abName);

        
        for (int i = 0; i < allDps.Length; i++)
            if (TempDPSAB_Dict.ContainsKey(allDps[i]))
            {
                TempDPSAB_Dict[allDps[i]].refCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                DpsContainer dc = new DpsContainer(null, allDps[i]);
             
                TempDPSAB_Dict[allDps[i]] = dc;
                StartCoroutine(SingleDpsABLoad(allDps[i]));
                yield return 0;
            }
                
         for (int i = 0; i < allDps.Length; i++)
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => TempDPSAB_Dict[allDps[i]].finishLoad);

        yield return 0;
        AssetBundleCreateRequest ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);

        yield return ab;
        GameObject go = null;

        AssetBundleRequest abReq = ab.assetBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync<GameObject>();
        yield return abReq;
        go = (GameObject)abReq.asset;

        TempABGO_Dict[abName] = new TempPrefabABPair(ab.assetBundle, go, allDps);
    
}
```

```
IEnumerator SingleDpsABLoad(string abName)
{
    DpsContainer dc = TempDPSAB_Dict[abName];
        AssetBundleCreateRequest ab = null;
        ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + abName);
        yield return ab;
        dc.AB = ab.assetBundle;
        AssetBundleRequest rq = ab.assetBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync();
        yield return rq;
        dc.finishLoad = true;        
}
```

This is what I used to build BuildAssetBundles.

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(Application.streamingAssetsPath, compressMode, EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First more a general note, you can use

yield return null;

and you can also probably reduce the amount of those a lot e.g. before and after

```
AssetBundleCreateRequest ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);
```

within the `for` loop etc.

And then within in your `SingleDpsABLoad`you do not wait for the

```
ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(....);
```

to actually finish! You just continue to immediately set

```
dc.finihed = true
```

so you might just be lucky that sometimes the rest of the redundant

```
yield return 0;
```

in the for loop etc are just delay enough to actually manage to load it in time ^^

---

So you probably could rather do something like

```
IEnumerator SingleDpsABLoad(DpsContainer dpsContainer)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, dpsContainer.abName);

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Can't find path:" + path);
        yield break;
    }

    var ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);  

    // actually wait until the async operation is done
    yield return ab;

    // can also make that one async
    yield return ab.assetBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync();

    dpsContainer.AB = ab.assetBundle;
    dpsContainer.finishLoad = true;
}

IEnumerator SingleTempGOABLoad(string abName)
{
    Debug.Log(" 1 SingleTempGOABLoad :" + abName);

    // personally I would start with that check here already
    var path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, abName);

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Debug.Log("Can't find path:" + path);
        yield break;
    }
    
    if (TempABGO_Dict.ContainsKey(abName)) yield break;

    var allDps = mainManifest.GetAllDependencies(abName);
         
    foreach (var dps in allDps)
    {
        if (TempDPSAB_Dict.TryGetValue(dps, out var dpsContainer))
        {
            dpsContainer.refCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            dpsContainer = new DpsContainer(null, dps);
            
            TempDPSAB_Dict[dps] = dpsContainer;
            StartCoroutine(SingleDpsABLoad(dps));
        }
    }
    
    // using System.Linq
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => TempDPSAB_Dict.All(kvp => kvp.Value.finishLoad));
   

    var ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);
    yield return ab;

    var abReq = ab.assetBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync<GameObject>();
    yield return abReq;

    var go = (GameObject)abReq.asset;
   
    TempABGO_Dict[abName] = new TempPrefabABPair(ab.assetBundle, go, allDps));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I had learned a lot through  your advices an code ,but unfortunately,I got same problem even through  I corrected my code that you metioned.

Comment: I notice that all my  prefab load form assetbundle that got error all shows one problem :lost animation clip，no other assets lost through loading.

Comment: As I mentioned, I used a dictionary to store dependencies assetbundle file and make sure do not repeat loading the same file. I found that wen I got a game object that lost animation clip, the assetbundle file of it's animator controller  has already in dictionary ,it means this file had been loaded completely. and the  animation clip shoulded be in this animator file .

Comment: @olooer would it be possible that you need to again recursively also load the dependencies of those first? Haven't worked with asset bundles too much .. maybe it is an issue that you load all dependencies as individual parallel .. maybe the animator one would need to wait until all the clips are loaded first? This would basically require to recursively bubble down until finding assets that don't have further dependencies -> load these first, then allow for the next higher level to finish loading etc

Comment: I had finaly slove this.This issue seems starts at I copied an animator form another game object to this one which lost animation clip.Even through I reassign all clips of the copied animator , it still carried many old  dependencies( that is weird ).

Comment: You seems right, a mass of redundant  assetbundle dependencies been added,and I haven't loaded to the most basic dependencies cause this issue. I fixed it by reduce all redundant dependencies, and now I try to recursively bubble down to load most basic dependencies. Thaks again!